# Drupal (Apache) behind Proxy

Tags: apache, cookies, proxy, drupal-7, f5

I have a **Drupal** 7 site running on an **Apache** webserver on server A with IP # a.2.3.4. This **site A** can be accessed and allows login using server A specific DNS.

Recently, this site has been put behind a corporate proxy server B (IP # b.5.6.7)  which uses **F5** for all proxy redirects. Lets call this **site B**.

**Issue**: I can access and login to site A - IP # a.2.3.4 without any issue. However, when I access site B (IP # b.5.6.7), I can access the site but i cannot login. I get ACCESS DENIED error on the login page after I hit SUBMIT.

**Observation**: 
Site A creates session cookies in the browser where as Site B cookies are not created.

Any help?

Comment: do you have access to the F5 device?

Comment: no, I do not. But I can make changes to it via F5 admin.